# pdf parzen window matlab

Tags: matlab, window, probability-density

I'm trying to calculate PDF probability function of Image by means of Parzen windows, but I don't understand why the result for each pixel value is the same.

I will try to explain better. If I choose width of parzen window and window function as a gaussian function, the PDF formula is :

[image: gaussian window function]

My Matlab code is:

```
d=1;
h=delta;
X=rand(20);
  function pdf=parzen(X,dim,delta)
pdf=zeros(20);
   for u=0:dim-2
           for v=0:dim-2
                for a=1+(u*dim):dim+(u*dim)
                     for b=1+(v*dim):dim+(v*dim)
                         for i=1+(u*dim):dim+(u*dim)
                            for j=1+(v*dim):dim+(v*dim)
                               ris=gaussianWindow((X(i,j)-X(a,b)),delta);
                                 pdf(a,b)=pdf(a,b)+ris;
                            end
                         end
                           pdf(a,b)=pdf(a,b)/(dim*dim);
                     end
                end
           end
   end

end


function result=gaussianWindow(val,delta)

   result=(1/(delta*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(double((-val*val))/(2*delta*delta));
end
```